# Webcam on Openbsd

Tags: openbsd, camera

```
# dmesg
...
uaudio0 at uhub1 port 2 configuration 1 interface 1 "vendor 0x093a product 0x2622" rev 1.10/1.00 addr 2
uaudio0: audio rev 1.00, 2 mixer controls
audio1 at uaudio0
ugen0 at uhub1 port 2 configuration 1 "vendor 0x093a product 0x2622" rev 1.10/1.00 addr 2
#
```

#

```
# usbdevs -v 
Controller /dev/usb0:
addr 1: high speed, self powered, config 1, EHCI root hub(0x0000), Intel(0x8086), rev 1.00
 port 1 powered
 port 2 powered
 port 3 powered
 port 4 powered
 port 5 addr 2: high speed, power 498 mA, config 1, UB6225(0x1606), ENE(0x0951), rev 1.00, iSerialNumber 146030377350
 port 6 powered
 port 7 powered
 port 8 powered
Controller /dev/usb1:
addr 1: full speed, self powered, config 1, UHCI root hub(0x0000), Intel(0x8086), rev 1.00
 port 1 powered
 port 2 addr 2: full speed, power 100 mA, config 1, product 0x2622(0x2622), vendor 0x093a(0x093a), rev 1.00
Controller /dev/usb2:
addr 1: full speed, self powered, config 1, UHCI root hub(0x0000), Intel(0x8086), rev 1.00
 port 1 powered
 port 2 powered
Controller /dev/usb3:
addr 1: full speed, self powered, config 1, UHCI root hub(0x0000), Intel(0x8086), rev 1.00
 port 1 powered
 port 2 powered
Controller /dev/usb4:
addr 1: full speed, self powered, config 1, UHCI root hub(0x0000), Intel(0x8086), rev 1.00
 port 1 powered
 port 2 powered
#
```

#

```
# fswebcam               
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
Error opening device: /dev/video0
open: Device not configured
Unable to find a source module that can read /dev/video0.
#
```

#

What am I missing? How can I configure the webcam so that we can export images from it with fswebcam on OpenBSD 5.1? The webcam is an eye312.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your webcam is not UVC compatible, and thus is not supported by the uvideo driver in OpenBSD. You would need to port the pac7302 driver from Linux to use this webcam.